# Помогите отправить запрос на сервер в в виде json

Tags: java, android

Здраствуйте! Помогите отправить запрос на сервер в в виде json:

```
{"clients":[{"id":"1","schet":"REAL","name":"Zhenia","account":"123456","broker":"Roboforex - Pro Cent","aktivation_license":"2019.03.26","to_license":"2019.03.30","email":"dcdd@tut.by","kto_privel":"Andrei"}],"success":1}
```

использую вот такой код:

```
public class NewClientActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private EditText editid;
        private EditText edittip;
    private EditText editname;
    private EditText editacc;
    private EditText editbrok;
    private EditText editaklic;
    private EditText edittplic;
    private EditText editmail;
    private EditText editktoprivel;
    private Button btnCreateProduct;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    // url to create new product
    private static String url_create_product = "http://sviterpro.had.su/Api/create_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_client);

// Showing and Enabling clicks on the Home/Up button
        if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

                editid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_id);
                edittip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_tip);
        editname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_Name);
        editacc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_Account);
        editbrok = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_Broker);
        editaklic = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_AktLic);
        edittplic = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_toLic);
        editmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_mail);
        editktoprivel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_ktoprivel);
        btnCreateProduct = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_create);

        btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewClientActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Идет добавление....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String id = editid.getText().toString();
            String tip = edittip.getText().toString();
            String name = editname.getText().toString();
            String acc = editacc.getText().toString();  
                  String brok = editbrok.getText().toString();
            String aklic = editaklic.getText().toString();
            String tplic = edittplic.getText().toString();          
                  String mail = editmail.getText().toString();
            String ktoprivel = editktoprivel.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> params = new                 ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("schet", tip ));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("account", acc));
                  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("broker", brok));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("aktivation_license", aklic));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to_license", tplic));
                  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", mail));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kto_privel", ktoprivel));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "GET", params);

            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

код JSONParser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

и мне постоянно выбивает ошибку вот тут:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "GET", params);
```

а в JSONParser вот тут:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

c ошибкой:

```
JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:49);
NewClientActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(NewClientActivity.java:107);
```

Comment: А этот json валидный?

Comment: Да....ссылка...http://sviterpro.had.su/Api/get_all_products.php

Comment: Советую обратить внимание на Retrofit - для подобных задач самое оно, а апачевский клиент давно вычеркнут из Андроида и, возможно, сам по себе вызывает ошибку ибо устарел.

Comment: Библиотека `org.apache.http` уже давно deprecated на Андроид, нет никакого смысла даже тратить время на исправление данного кода.